# mysqli prepared statement where var = var dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

If I have a prepared statement as follows:

> $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc, from tablea where $option = ?" )

Is it possible to prepare the `$option` variable as well?

Note: the `$option` variable comes from a drop down list as follows

```
<select name="option">
  <option value="blah1">blah1</option>
  <option value="blah2">blah2</option>
  <option value="blah3">blah3</option>
  <option value="blah4">blah4</option>
</select>
```

and the other field comes from a simple input text box. This field will fill up the `?` in the prepared statement.

Comment: you cannot bind table or column names

Answer (score 0):

you can use method "bindParam"

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");  
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name); $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind tables or columns because prepare escapes them automatically and will cause a syntax issue. Also, when preparing like this it's advisable not to use a variable in the query because you're bypassing the binding process which basically defeats the purpose of preparing. Just make sure to validate/sanitize your text input. There are a lot of options, here are a few.

**Option #1:**

```
switch ($option) {
case "blah1":
    $query = "SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc, from tablea where blah1=?";
    break;
case "blah2":
    $query = "SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc, from tablea where blah2=?";
    break;
case "blah3":
    $query = "SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc, from tablea where blah3=?";
    break;
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam('s', $input);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

**Option #2:**

```
$whitelist = ["blah1","blah2","blah3"];
If (in_array($option, $whitelist)) { //at this point variable is safe to use//
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc, from tablea where $option=?");
    $stmt->bindParam('s', $input);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "unexpected value";
}
```

Comment: What would be the workaround for this dynamically set variable?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");  
$stmt->execute(array($_REQUEST['name'],$_REQUEST['value']));
```

But this is **not secure**!

I suggest to use:

```
// Read values to $name and $value
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");  
$stmt->execute(array($name,$value));
```

For your requirement:

```
// if there is a value in $option
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc, from tablea where $option = ?" );
$stmt->execute(array($option));
```